# Which is better when using Entity Framework: using linq (or lambda expressions) for all transactions or all stored procedures

Tags: sql, linq, entity-framework, stored-procedures, lambda

I love Entity Framework. I also hate stored procedures; so I code all my applications using lambda expressions ...

I never use cursors and 99% of my transactions are CRUD. Other than precompilation do stored procedures via the Entity Framework provide me any benefits that anyone can suggest?

Comment: @marc_s That is very wrong.  Stored procedures can be pre-compiled, and often are.  They aren't cached just like a normal T-SQL query, but with the advancements in SQL plan caching in the past 10 years the benefits aren't usually as dramatic.  Perhaps you are confusing this with a non-materialized view?

Comment: @marc_s Those articles deal with the plan cache, which while is a major part of executing a query, is still only one part of many.  Adhoc queries are cached and flushed slightly different (adhocs are more likely to be flushed).  Correctly matching a adhoc can be more troublesome, especially when dealing with constant string parameters (if 'Hello' is passed as varchar(5) instead of varchar(80), the plans don't match).  If your SQL server is set to optimize for adhoc queries, the adhoc query isn't cached until the second execution.

Comment: I could be mistaken, but I believe adhoc queries still need to go through syntax checks while stored procs do not (minor difference in speed).  Also, if the queries can be long, obviously it takes more time to transmit the query as an adhoc to the server than just by name.

Answer (score 3):

EF LINQ is a layer of abstraction over the SQL commands, and that means two things:

- Performance of SQL SPs could be better since you are not limited to LINQ extensions, therefore you could potentially use SQL server capabilities more efficiently if you, especially if you want to write some batching that internally generate temporal tables and temporal indices.
- LINQ has infinite composeability, and LINQ-to-SQL flavor is compatible with LINQ-to-Objects that simplifies migration/mixing in-memory/in-db collection operations.

So SP approach gives you fine tuning and EF LINQ gives you generic query language functionality.